# Site optimisation, Specify image dimensions with responsive theme?

Tags: magento-1.9, optimization

I am currently optimising my site for faster page load speeds.

Should I specify image dimensions for the images on the main page if I am using a responsive theme?

Another way of putting it.

By specifying the dimensions of the images is this likely to cause any problem with image resizing as browser size changes, or use on mobile sites etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the image dimension using style or other html attributes, this will not change the images file size, so the loading time for the image file will be the same.

If you specify the image dimension in the phtml template where the image is generated, like

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(200)
```

then the template should be made in such a way to not oversize the image to show it pixelated.